# If $f(g(n))$ has a limit, does $g(n)$ too?

Tags: limits

If $f(g(n))$ has a limit, does $g(n)$ too?

For example let $f(n) = 1-n$ and $g(n) = \frac{1}{n}$, then $f(g(n)) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$

I am looking for an answer to the general question.

Comment: You shouldn't write $f(n)$ as if $f$ was defined on $\mathbb N$. In practical cases, it will be defined on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 7):

No. For example if $f(x)=\text{constant}$ it doesn't matter what $g(x)$ is so long as it is defined.

Answer (score 2):

For a non-trival example, take

$$f(x):=1-\frac 1x$$ and $$g(n):=(-1)^nn.$$